# Inserting multipe values in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to insert values into a table using a for loop. I can't understand why it isnt working. I am a beginner. Any help would be appreciated.

```
create or replace procedure valueinput
as i number;
begin
for i in 1..10
   loop
     man_id number:=&Manager_Id;
     man_fname varchar2(100):=&First_Name;
     man_lname varchar2(100):=&Last_Name;
     emp_id number:=&Employee_ID_Managed;
     insert into managerinfo
     values (man_id,man_fname,man_lname,emp_id);
     i:=i+1;
   end loop;
end;
```

Comment: what is value pass in i???

Comment: why you increment the loop for manually  (i:=i+1;)? 
What is the error message that you get ?
May be you have a auto increment field?!

Comment: Are you expecting it to prompt you within each loop for a manager id, first name etc?

Answer (score 1):

You must declare your variables in the DECLARATION section of your PL/SQL block, right now you're trying to do it in the EXECUTION section.

Also, for a PL/SQL FOR..IN loop, you don't need to declare or increment your index.

Try something like this-

```
create or replace procedure valueinput
as 
 man_id number;
 man_fname varchar2(100);
 man_lname varchar2(100);
 emp_id number;
begin
for i in 1..10
   loop
     man_id :=&Manager_Id;
     man_fname :=&First_Name;
     man_lname :=&Last_Name;
     emp_id :=&Employee_ID_Managed;

     insert into managerinfo
     values (man_id,man_fname,man_lname,emp_id);
   end loop;
end;
```

It would also be best practice to declare your variable types as the same as the table column that you're inserting into.

For example-

```
man_id managerinfo.manager_id%TYPE;
```